# Create a spectrogram in Node.js

Tags: node.js, audio, web-audio-api, spectrogram

How can I extract the time/frequency/amplitude information from a WAV (or AIFF)? I want a spectrogram as a an array, e.g.

```
[ 
  [ // 1st sample, time
    [frequency1_t1, amplitude_f1t1], [frequency2_t1, amplitude_f2t1], ...
  ],
  [ // 2nd sample, time
    [frequency1_t2, amplitude_f1t2], [frequency2_t2, amplitude_f2t2], ...
  ]
]
```

(or similar, the shape is not relevant)

**At the moment I don't understand:**

I would expect an array with values for each frequency in the spectrum. E.g. 0.2 for 40Hz, 0.3 for 41Hz and so on... but I get an array with the half of the sample length.

Code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const fs = require('fs');
const ft = require('fourier-transform');
const db = require('decibels');
const sine = require('audio-oscillator/sin');
const WaveFile = require('wavefile');
const {unpackArray} = require('byte-data');


const generateLength =  1024// 11289600; // 1024

/**
 * Return the sample at a given index.
 * @param {number} startIndex The sample start index.
 * @param {number} stopIndex The sample stop index.
 * @return {number} The sample.
 * @throws {Error} If the sample index is off range.
 */
const getSamples = (wav, startIndex, stopIndex) => {
    startIndex = startIndex * (wav.dataType.bits / 8);
    stopIndex = stopIndex * (wav.dataType.bits / 8);
    if (stopIndex + wav.dataType.bits / 8 > wav.data.samples.length) {
        throw new Error('Range error');
    }
    return unpackArray(
        wav.data.samples.slice(startIndex, stopIndex),
        wav.dataType
    );
};
    
/**
 * Generate a sine wave
 */
const generateWav = () => {
    // generate sine wave 440 Hz
    const waveform = sine(generateLength, 440); // samples, frequency
    return waveform
};

/**
 * Read a wav file from disk
 */
const readWav = (callback) => {
    // return callback(null, generateWav())
    if (process.env.GENERATE === 'true') {
        return callback(null, generateWav())
    }

    let wav;
    // read the wav file
    const filePath = process.env.AUDIO_IN_FOLDER + process.env.AUDIO_FILE;
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, buffer) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        wav = new WaveFile(buffer);
        
        const samples = getSamples(wav, 0, 1024);
        return callback(null, samples);
    })
};

/**
 * Process the wav
*/
readWav((err, samples) => {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }

    // in case I create the sine wave, I get an array of length 1024, with values from -1 to +1
    // the same applies for the wav
    console.log('samples', samples, samples.length);

    // get normalized magnitudes for frequencies from 0 to 22050 with interval 44100/1024 ≈ 43Hz
    // I get an array of length 512 (probably 1024/ 2 channels) with value from 0 - 0.7 (max prob. 1)
  
    const spectrum = ft(samples);
    console.table(spectrum);

    // //convert to decibels
    // const decibels = spectrum.map((value) => db.fromGain(value));
    // console.table(decibels);
});
```

I would like to retrieve the amplitudes at the diff. frequencies.

PS:
I managed to do this in the browser with the web audio API but the only package I found for node.js so far is:
https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api which is abandoned.

EDIT: I found another library which delivers more plausible results:

```
const fft = require('fft-js').fft;
const fftUtil = require('fft-js').util;

/**
 * Process the wav
 */

const phasors = fft(generateWav());

const frequencies = fftUtil.fftFreq(phasors, 44100), // Sample rate and coef is just used for length, and frequency step
    magnitudes = fftUtil.fftMag(phasors);

const both = frequencies.map(function (f, ix) {
    return {frequency: f, magnitude: magnitudes[ix]};
});

console.table(both);
```

Output:

```
┌─────────┬────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ (index) │   frequency    │     magnitude      │
├─────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│    0    │       0        │ 12.152954611168916 │
│    1    │  43.06640625   │ 12.371840124428138 │
│    2    │   86.1328125   │ 13.049660038632785 │
│    3    │  129.19921875  │ 14.257748464539002 │
│    4    │   172.265625   │ 16.145493015641954 │
│    5    │  215.33203125  │ 19.006782054318574 │
│    6    │  258.3984375   │ 23.444013431023404 │
│    7    │  301.46484375  │ 30.839530345061696 │
│    8    │   344.53125    │ 45.104565448543774 │
│    9    │  387.59765625  │ 83.05529774944604  │
│   10    │  430.6640625   │ 471.99329683509916 │
│   11    │  473.73046875  │ 132.38812248080427 │
│   12    │   516.796875   │ 58.94894310683054  │
│   13    │  559.86328125  │ 38.29097615220791  │
│   14    │  602.9296875   │ 28.55339797808452  │
│   15    │  645.99609375  │  22.8834459943328  │
│   16    │    689.0625    │ 19.169092636055744 │
│   17    │  732.12890625  │ 16.544346462620222 │
│   18    │  775.1953125   │ 14.588639163496254 │
│   19    │  818.26171875  │ 13.073165838642582 │
│   20    │   861.328125   │ 11.862817675507356 │
│   21    │  904.39453125  │ 10.872696852206447 │
│   22    │  947.4609375   │ 10.04678419250667  │
│   23    │  990.52734375  │ 9.346626225654326  │
│   24    │   1033.59375   │ 8.744951406922706  │
│   25    │ 1076.66015625  │ 8.221880329631402  │
│   26    │  1119.7265625  │ 7.762578689775234  │
│   27    │ 1162.79296875  │ 7.355750727231507  │
│   28    │  1205.859375   │ 6.992641946837161  │
│   29    │ 1248.92578125  │ 6.666361076689498  │
│   30    │  1291.9921875  │ 6.371408134738898  │
│   31    │ 1335.05859375  │ 6.103339064749246  │
│   32    │    1378.125    │ 5.858522971508816  │
│   33    │ 1421.19140625  │ 5.633963445745503  │
│   34    │  1464.2578125  │ 5.427165073795851  │
│   35    │ 1507.32421875  │ 5.236032340013399  │
│   36    │  1550.390625   │ 5.058792106400648  │
│   37    │ 1593.45703125  │ 4.893933492369614  │
│   38    │  1636.5234375  │  4.74016075996692  │
│   39    │ 1679.58984375  │ 4.596356034064684  │
│   40    │   1722.65625   │ 4.461549540593798  │
│   41    │ 1765.72265625  │ 4.334895649436749  │
│   42    │  1808.7890625  │  4.21565344088737  │
│   43    │ 1851.85546875  │  4.10317082794807  │
│   44    │  1894.921875   │ 3.9968714964351753 │
│   45    │ 1937.98828125  │ 3.896244094995214  │
│   46    │  1981.0546875  │ 3.8008332343806863 │
│   47    │ 2024.12109375  │ 3.710231951372898  │
│   48    │   2067.1875    │ 3.624075365850696  │
│   49    │ 2110.25390625  │ 3.5420353156097173 │
│   50    │  2153.3203125  │ 3.463815796922526  │
│   51    │ 2196.38671875  │ 3.3891490726204667 │
│   52    │  2239.453125   │ 3.317792335974296  │
│   53    │ 2282.51953125  │ 3.2495248395633305 │
│   54    │  2325.5859375  │ 3.184145414927604  │
│   55    │ 2368.65234375  │ 3.121470322059914  │
│   56    │   2411.71875   │ 3.0613313784448493 │
│   57    │ 2454.78515625  │ 3.0035743259530703 │
│   58    │  2497.8515625  │ 2.9480574008737856 │
│   59    │ 2540.91796875  │ 2.8946500780591413 │
│   60    │  2583.984375   │ 2.843231964813001  │
│   61    │ 2627.05078125  │ 2.7936918239895956 │
│   62    │  2670.1171875  │ 2.7459267089345327 │
│   63    │ 2713.18359375  │ 2.6998411955269557 │
│   64    │    2756.25     │  2.65534669876918  │
│   65    │ 2799.31640625  │ 2.6123608631974977 │
│   66    │  2842.3828125  │ 2.570807017921727  │
│   67    │ 2885.44921875  │ 2.5306136883907895 │
│   68    │  2928.515625   │ 2.491714158071842  │
│   69    │ 2971.58203125  │ 2.4540460741530628 │
│   70    │  3014.6484375  │ 2.4175510921649352 │
│   71    │ 3057.71484375  │ 2.3821745550828988 │
│   72    │   3100.78125   │ 2.3478652030460068 │
│   73    │ 3143.84765625  │ 2.3145749103153315 │
│   74    │  3186.9140625  │ 2.282258446516979  │
│   75    │ 3229.98046875  │ 2.2508732595769505 │
│   76    │  3273.046875   │ 2.220379278067911  │
│   77    │ 3316.11328125  │ 2.1907387309594126 │
│   78    │  3359.1796875  │ 2.1619159829977477 │
│   79    │ 3402.24609375  │ 2.1338773841468113 │
│   80    │   3445.3125    │ 2.1065911316990023 │
│   81    │ 3488.37890625  │ 2.0800271438214692 │
│   82    │  3531.4453125  │ 2.054156943439062  │
│   83    │ 3574.51171875  │ 2.0289535514749724 │
│   84    │  3617.578125   │ 2.0043913885751485 │
│   85    │ 3660.64453125  │ 1.9804461845350614 │
│   86    │  3703.7109375  │ 1.9570948947290032 │
│   87    │ 3746.77734375  │ 1.9343156229142768 │
│   88    │   3789.84375   │ 1.9120875498459815 │
│   89    │ 3832.91015625  │ 1.8903908671957874 │
│   90    │  3875.9765625  │ 1.8692067163169377 │
│   91    │ 3919.04296875  │ 1.8485171314433517 │
│   92    │  3962.109375   │ 1.8283049869505235 │
│   93    │ 4005.17578125  │ 1.8085539483406927 │
│   94    │  4048.2421875  │ 1.789248426647436  │
│   95    │ 4091.30859375  │ 1.770373535982654  │
│   96    │    4134.375    │ 1.7519150539745088 │
│   97    │ 4177.44140625  │ 1.733859384867805  │
│   98    │  4220.5078125  │ 1.7161935250787304 │
│   99    │ 4263.57421875  │ 1.6989050310145166 │
│   100   │  4306.640625   │ 1.6819819889848078 │
│   101   │ 4349.70703125  │ 1.6654129870471555 │
│   102   │  4392.7734375  │ 1.649187088641961  │
│   103   │ 4435.83984375  │ 1.6332938078849353 │
│   104   │   4478.90625   │ 1.6177230863958667 │
│   105   │ 4521.97265625  │ 1.6024652715528576 │
│   106   │  4565.0390625  │ 1.5875110960700973 │
│   107   │ 4608.10546875  │ 1.5728516588054446 │
│   108   │  4651.171875   │ 1.5584784067120494 │
│   109   │ 4694.23828125  │ 1.5443831178544063 │
│   110   │  4737.3046875  │ 1.5305578854161885 │
│   111   │ 4780.37109375  │ 1.5169951026323973 │
│   112   │   4823.4375    │ 1.503687448583734  │
│   113   │ 4866.50390625  │ 1.4906278747959294 │
│   114   │  4909.5703125  │ 1.4778095925909394 │
│   115   │ 4952.63671875  │ 1.465226061140952  │
│   116   │  4995.703125   │ 1.452870976179976  │
│   117   │ 5038.76953125  │ 1.4407382593305655 │
│   118   │  5081.8359375  │ 1.4288220480072211 │
│   119   │ 5124.90234375  │ 1.4171166858597923 │
│   120   │   5167.96875   │ 1.4056167137234505 │
│   121   │ 5211.03515625  │ 1.3943168610441796 │
│   122   │  5254.1015625  │ 1.383212037750449  │
│   123   │ 5297.16796875  │ 1.3722973265443272 │
│   124   │  5340.234375   │ 1.3615679755866048 │
│   125   │ 5383.30078125  │ 1.3510193915528388 │
│   126   │  5426.3671875  │ 1.3406471330380145 │
│   127   │ 5469.43359375  │ 1.3304469042899936 │
│   128   │     5512.5     │ 1.3204145492521742 │
│   129   │ 5555.56640625  │ 1.310546045897987  │
│   130   │  5598.6328125  │ 1.3008375008404036 │
│   131   │ 5641.69921875  │ 1.291285144201002  │
│   132   │  5684.765625   │ 1.2818853247240856 │
│   133   │ 5727.83203125  │ 1.2726345051221066 │
│   134   │  5770.8984375  │ 1.2635292576398605 │
│   135   │ 5813.96484375  │ 1.2545662598252671 │
│   136   │   5857.03125   │ 1.2457422904957558 │
│   137   │ 5900.09765625  │ 1.2370542258895871 │
│   138   │  5943.1640625  │ 1.2284990359922503 │
│   139   │ 5986.23046875  │ 1.2200737810288795 │
│   140   │  6029.296875   │ 1.2117756081135687 │
│   141   │ 6072.36328125  │ 1.2036017480478065 │
│   142   │  6115.4296875  │ 1.1955495122601592 │
│   143   │ 6158.49609375  │ 1.1876162898798384 │
│   144   │   6201.5625    │ 1.1797995449375729 │
│   145   │ 6244.62890625  │ 1.1720968136870935 │
│   146   │  6287.6953125  │ 1.164505702041419  │
│   147   │ 6330.76171875  │ 1.1570238831180508 │
│   148   │  6373.828125   │ 1.1496490948877365 │
│   149   │ 6416.89453125  │ 1.1423791379217956 │
│   150   │  6459.9609375  │ 1.1352118732330423 │
│   151   │ 6503.02734375  │ 1.1281452202060451 │
│   152   │   6546.09375   │ 1.121177154611966  │
│   153   │ 6589.16015625  │ 1.1143057067045552 │
│   154   │  6632.2265625  │ 1.1075289593929885 │
│   155   │ 6675.29296875  │ 1.1008450464880004 │
│   156   │  6718.359375   │ 1.0942521510181538 │
│   157   │ 6761.42578125  │ 1.0877485036126562 │
│   158   │  6804.4921875  │ 1.0813323809478814 │
│   159   │ 6847.55859375  │ 1.0750021042545954 │
│   160   │    6890.625    │ 1.0687560378830854 │
│   161   │ 6933.69140625  │ 1.0625925879237053 │
│   162   │  6976.7578125  │ 1.0565102008801939 │
│   163   │ 7019.82421875  │ 1.0505073623935723 │
│   164   │  7062.890625   │ 1.0445825960142023 │
│   165   │ 7105.95703125  │ 1.038734462020084  │
│   166   │  7149.0234375  │ 1.0329615562791732 │
│   167   │ 7192.08984375  │ 1.0272625091539958 │
│   168   │   7235.15625   │ 1.0216359844465652 │
│   169   │ 7278.22265625  │ 1.0160806783819898 │
│   170   │  7321.2890625  │ 1.0105953186290697 │
│   171   │ 7364.35546875  │ 1.0051786633563107 │
│   172   │  7407.421875   │ 0.999829500321966  │
│   173   │ 7450.48828125  │ 0.994546645996437  │
│   174   │  7493.5546875  │ 0.9893289447159996 │
│   175   │ 7536.62109375  │ 0.9841752678663415 │
│   176   │   7579.6875    │ 0.979084513094743  │
│   177   │ 7622.75390625  │ 0.9740556035497749 │
│   178   │  7665.8203125  │ 0.9690874871473424 │
│   179   │ 7708.88671875  │ 0.9641791358620374 │
│   180   │  7751.953125   │ 0.9593295450427901 │
│   181   │ 7795.01953125  │ 0.9545377327518263 │
│   182   │  7838.0859375  │ 0.9498027391260084 │
│   183   │ 7881.15234375  │ 0.9451236257597078 │
│   184   │   7924.21875   │ 0.9404994751083671 │
│   185   │ 7967.28515625  │ 0.9359293899118848 │
│   186   │  8010.3515625  │ 0.9314124926370905 │
│   187   │ 8053.41796875  │ 0.9269479249386134 │
│   188   │  8096.484375   │ 0.922534847137409  │
│   189   │ 8139.55078125  │ 0.9181724377161812 │
│   190   │  8182.6171875  │ 0.9138598928313305 │
│   191   │ 8225.68359375  │ 0.9095964258403147 │
│   192   │    8268.75     │ 0.9053812668445473 │
│   193   │ 8311.81640625  │ 0.9012136622464734 │
│   194   │  8354.8828125  │ 0.8970928743209342 │
│   195   │ 8397.94921875  │ 0.8930181807999668 │
│   196   │  8441.015625   │ 0.8889888744705485 │
│   197   │ 8484.08203125  │ 0.8850042627850117 │
│   198   │  8527.1484375  │ 0.8810636674834446 │
│   199   │ 8570.21484375  │ 0.8771664242277897 │
│   200   │   8613.28125   │ 0.8733118822471652 │
│   201   │ 8656.34765625  │ 0.8694994039939781 │
│   202   │  8699.4140625  │ 0.8657283648106044 │
│   203   │ 8742.48046875  │ 0.8619981526059125 │
│   204   │  8785.546875   │ 0.8583081675418567 │
│   205   │ 8828.61328125  │ 0.8546578217290682 │
│   206   │  8871.6796875  │ 0.8510465389317811 │
│   207   │ 8914.74609375  │ 0.8474737542813985 │
│   208   │   8957.8125    │ 0.8439389139984876 │
│   209   │ 9000.87890625  │ 0.8404414751229206 │
│   210   │  9043.9453125  │ 0.8369809052519736 │
│   211   │ 9087.01171875  │ 0.8335566822859806 │
│   212   │  9130.078125   │ 0.8301682941811723 │
│   213   │ 9173.14453125  │ 0.8268152387099789 │
│   214   │  9216.2109375  │ 0.8234970232278401 │
│   215   │ 9259.27734375  │ 0.820213164446897  │
│   216   │   9302.34375   │ 0.8169631882159036 │
│   217   │ 9345.41015625  │ 0.813746629306537  │
│   218   │  9388.4765625  │ 0.8105630312055566 │
│   219   │ 9431.54296875  │ 0.8074119459128286 │
│   220   │  9474.609375   │ 0.8042929337449944 │
│   221   │ 9517.67578125  │ 0.8012055631444901 │
│   222   │  9560.7421875  │ 0.7981494104939528 │
│   223   │ 9603.80859375  │ 0.7951240599355628 │
│   224   │    9646.875    │ 0.7921291031954435 │
│   225   │ 9689.94140625  │ 0.7891641394127583 │
│   226   │  9733.0078125  │ 0.7862287749734875 │
│   227   │ 9776.07421875  │ 0.783322623348609  │
│   228   │  9819.140625   │ 0.7804453049366743 │
│   229   │ 9862.20703125  │ 0.7775964469105909 │
│   230   │  9905.2734375  │ 0.7747756830683817 │
│   231   │ 9948.33984375  │ 0.7719826536880043 │
│   232   │   9991.40625   │ 0.7692170053859664 │
│   233   │ 10034.47265625 │ 0.7664783909795868 │
│   234   │ 10077.5390625  │ 0.7637664693528738 │
│   235   │ 10120.60546875 │ 0.7610809053259505 │
│   236   │  10163.671875  │ 0.7584213695278121 │
│   237   │ 10206.73828125 │ 0.7557875382722999 │
│   238   │ 10249.8046875  │ 0.7531790934373814 │
│   239   │ 10292.87109375 │ 0.7505957223474149 │
│   240   │   10335.9375   │ 0.7480371176584374 │
│   241   │ 10379.00390625 │ 0.745502977246369  │
│   242   │ 10422.0703125  │ 0.7429930040980557 │
│   243   │ 10465.13671875 │ 0.7405069062049577 │
│   244   │  10508.203125  │ 0.738044396459589  │
│   245   │ 10551.26953125 │ 0.7356051925545116 │
│   246   │ 10594.3359375  │ 0.7331890168837784 │
│   247   │ 10637.40234375 │ 0.7307955964470021 │
│   248   │  10680.46875   │ 0.7284246627553796 │
│   249   │ 10723.53515625 │ 0.7260759517404931 │
│   250   │ 10766.6015625  │  0.72374920366505  │
│   251   │ 10809.66796875 │ 0.7214441630358492 │
│   252   │  10852.734375  │ 0.7191605785188439 │
│   253   │ 10895.80078125 │ 0.716898202856309  │
│   254   │ 10938.8671875  │ 0.7146567927859353 │
│   255   │ 10981.93359375 │ 0.712436108961887  │
│   256   │     11025      │ 0.7102359158777101 │
│   257   │ 11068.06640625 │ 0.7080559817911036 │
│   258   │ 11111.1328125  │ 0.7058960786504748 │
│   259   │ 11154.19921875 │ 0.7037559820231458 │
│   260   │  11197.265625  │ 0.7016354710253743 │
│   261   │ 11240.33203125 │ 0.6995343282538382 │
│   262   │ 11283.3984375  │ 0.6974523397188923 │
│   263   │ 11326.46484375 │ 0.6953892947792317 │
│   264   │  11369.53125   │ 0.6933449860781569 │
│   265   │ 11412.59765625 │ 0.6913192094812238 │
│   266   │ 11455.6640625  │ 0.6893117640154295 │
│   267   │ 11498.73046875 │ 0.6873224518095441 │
│   268   │  11541.796875  │ 0.6853510780362898 │
│   269   │ 11584.86328125 │ 0.6833974508552063 │
│   270   │ 11627.9296875  │ 0.6814613813572552 │
│   271   │ 11670.99609375 │ 0.6795426835105075 │
│   272   │   11714.0625   │ 0.677641174107065  │
│   273   │ 11757.12890625 │ 0.6757566727111779 │
│   274   │ 11800.1953125  │ 0.6738890016084861 │
│   275   │ 11843.26171875 │ 0.6720379857564167 │
│   276   │  11886.328125  │ 0.6702034527356622 │
│   277   │ 11929.39453125 │ 0.6683852327027254 │
│   278   │ 11972.4609375  │ 0.6665831583435046 │
│   279   │ 12015.52734375 │ 0.6647970648279368 │
│   280   │  12058.59375   │ 0.663026789765516  │
│   281   │ 12101.66015625 │ 0.661272173161877  │
│   282   │ 12144.7265625  │ 0.6595330573763096 │
│   283   │ 12187.79296875 │ 0.6578092870801286 │
│   284   │  12230.859375  │ 0.6561007092160064 │
│   285   │ 12273.92578125 │ 0.6544071729580885 │
│   286   │ 12316.9921875  │ 0.6527285296730775 │
│   287   │ 12360.05859375 │ 0.6510646328820283 │
│   288   │   12403.125    │ 0.6494153382230178 │
│   289   │ 12446.19140625 │ 0.6477805034145884 │
│   290   │ 12489.2578125  │ 0.646159988219951  │
│   291   │ 12532.32421875 │ 0.6445536544119334 │
│   292   │  12575.390625  │ 0.6429613657386952 │
│   293   │ 12618.45703125 │ 0.6413829878901197 │
│   294   │ 12661.5234375  │ 0.6398183884648961 │
│   295   │ 12704.58984375 │ 0.6382674369383002 │
│   296   │  12747.65625   │ 0.6367300046307028 │
│   297   │ 12790.72265625 │ 0.6352059646765789 │
│   298   │ 12833.7890625  │ 0.6336951919942735 │
│   299   │ 12876.85546875 │ 0.6321975632563025 │
│   300   │  12919.921875  │ 0.6307129568604022 │
│   301   │ 12962.98828125 │ 0.6292412529009501 │
│   302   │ 13006.0546875  │ 0.6277823331411194 │
│   303   │ 13049.12109375 │ 0.626336080985555  │
│   304   │   13092.1875   │ 0.6249023814535887 │
│   305   │ 13135.25390625 │ 0.6234811211530132 │
│   306   │ 13178.3203125  │ 0.6220721882543192 │
│   307   │ 13221.38671875 │ 0.6206754724655292 │
│   308   │  13264.453125  │ 0.6192908650074535 │
│   309   │ 13307.51953125 │ 0.6179182585895316 │
│   310   │ 13350.5859375  │ 0.6165575473859886 │
│   311   │ 13393.65234375 │ 0.6152086270126826 │
│   312   │  13436.71875   │ 0.6138713945041759 │
│   313   │ 13479.78515625 │ 0.6125457482914228 │
│   314   │ 13522.8515625  │ 0.6112315881798147 │
│   315   │ 13565.91796875 │ 0.6099288153276872 │
│   316   │  13608.984375  │ 0.6086373322251584 │
│   317   │ 13652.05078125 │ 0.6073570426735272 │
│   318   │ 13695.1171875  │ 0.6060878517649428 │
│   319   │ 13738.18359375 │ 0.6048296658624938 │
│   320   │    13781.25    │ 0.6035823925807031 │
│   321   │ 13824.31640625 │ 0.6023459407663738 │
│   322   │ 13867.3828125  │ 0.6011202204798132 │
│   323   │ 13910.44921875 │ 0.5999051429763976 │
│   324   │  13953.515625  │ 0.5987006206885245 │
│   325   │ 13996.58203125 │ 0.5975065672078168 │
│   326   │ 14039.6484375  │ 0.5963228972677794 │
│   327   │ 14082.71484375 │ 0.5951495267266942 │
│   328   │  14125.78125   │ 0.5939863725508676 │
│   329   │ 14168.84765625 │ 0.592833352798187  │
│   330   │ 14211.9140625  │ 0.5916903866019808 │
│   331   │ 14254.98046875 │ 0.5905573941551976 │
│   332   │  14298.046875  │ 0.5894342966948477 │

│   511   │ 22006.93359375 │ 0.5015789716443024 │
└─────────┴────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Any luck? There's popular libraries for C# and Python. Couldn't find one for JS.

Comment: it looks like everything depends on wav.dataType.bits can you please share the audio file you processin

Answer (score 3):

> At the moment I don't understand:
>
> I would expect an array with values for each frequency in the spectrum. E.g. 0.2 for 40Hz, 0.3 for 41Hz and so on... but I get an array with the half of the sample length.

The maximum frequency that can be represented without distortion is not equal the sampling frequency. It's half of it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency